# ERROR WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge when adding more that 10 columns to a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable

I am trying to add 2 more hidden columns to my datatable but I keep on receiving the URI is too large error as well as "ERROR TypeError: can't convert nil into an exact number"

```
Started GET "/assets/datatables/emails_datatable.self-cd9ac92f42d16be45f44ff8a616bd1ed9ff6e16588934ecabaadfff5000e4db2.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2017-07-21 14:46:15 -0400 
[2017-07-21 14:46:15] ERROR WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge 
[2017-07-21 14:46:15] ERROR TypeError: can't convert nil into an exact number 
/Users/kristianquincosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:226:in `-' 
/Users/kristianquincosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:226:in `minus_with_duration' 
/Users/kristianquincosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:237:in `minus_with_coercion' 
/Users/kristianquincosa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/accesslog.rb:111:in `setup_params' 
/Users/kristianquincosa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:219:in `access_log' 
/Users/kristianquincosa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `run' 
/Users/kristianquincosa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

that is the entire error message

These are my columns specified in my email_broadcasts_datatable.rb (the commented column are the ones that trigger the error)

```
def data
  email_broadcasts.map do |broadcast|
    [
      broadcast.id,
      broadcast.email_clickthroughs_count,
      broadcast.email_abuse_reports_count,
      # broadcast.email_unsubscribes_count,
      # broadcast.email_opens_count,
      broadcast.status.titleize,
      broadcast.scheduled,
      broadcast.subject,
      broadcast.user.email,
      broadcast.updated_at.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").strftime('%B %-d, %Y %l:%M%P'),
      link_to('', edit_email_broadcast_path(broadcast), class: "btn btn-primary fa fa-cog"),
      link_to('', email_broadcast_path(broadcast), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this email broadcast?"}, :remote => true, class: "btn btn-danger fa fa-trash delete_email_broadcast")
    ]
  end
end
```

Also this is my javascript code for the datatable.

```
//Code for emails datatable

$(function() {

  $('#emails').DataTable({
    pageLength: 10,
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    ajax: $('#emails').data('source'),
    dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
    buttons: [
    { extend: 'copy'},
    {extend: 'csv'},
    {extend: 'excel', title: 'Emails'},
    {extend: 'pdf', title: 'Emails'},
    {extend: 'print',
    customize: function (win){
      $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
      $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

      $(win.document.body).find('table')
      .addClass('compact')
      .css('font-size', 'inherit');
    }
  }
  ],
  columnDefs: [
  {
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
      return data + ' ' + row[10] + ' ' + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#stats"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i></button>';
    },
    targets: 9
  },
    {
    targets: [ 0 ], //,9,10,11 
    visible: false,
    searchable: false
  },

  {
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {

      switch(data) {
        case "Draft":
        return "<span class='label label-primary'>" + data + "</span>"
        case "In Queue":
        return "<span class='label label-warning'>" + data + "</span>"
        case "Completed":
        return "<span class='label label-success'>" + data + "</span>"
        case "Processing":
        return "<span class='label label-info'>" + data + "</span>"
        default:
        break;
      }
    },
    targets: 4
  },
  {
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {

      if (data) {
                            //True
                            return "<span class='label label-success'>Yes</span>"
                          } else {
                            return "<span class='label label-danger'>No</span>"
                          }
                        },
                        targets: 5
                      },
                      {
                        orderable: false,
                        targets: [5,8,9]
                      }   
                      ],
                      order: [[0, 'desc' ]],
                      columns: [
                      { width: "0%" },
                      { width: "2%" },
                      { width: "2%" },
                      { width: "8%" },
                      { width: "8%" },
                      { width: "30%" },
                      { width: "18%" },
                      { width: "18%" },
                      { width: "12%" }
                      ]
                    });
});
```

And this is my table in HTML

```
<table id="emails" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" data-source="<%= email_broadcasts_path(format: :json) %>">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Click Throughs</th>
      <th>Abuse</th>
    <!--  <th>Unsuscribes</th>
     <th>Opens</th> -->
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Scheduled</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Created By</th>
      <th>Updated</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with WEBrick itself. It has an internal limit to the URL length.

You should run another web server like Puma, Thin, or Unicorn.

Add the following to your `Gemfile` to run one of those locally

```
group :development do 
  gem 'puma'
end
```